# Fully manual spring boot initialization

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jetty

I don't want to use @SprintBootApplication, but in my manual version routing is not working and wget "/" gets 404.

```
@Controller
@Configuration
//@SpringBootApplication
@Import(SimpleController.Ctx.class)
public class SimpleController {
    public static class Ctx {
        @Bean
        public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory() {
            return new JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(8888);
        }
        @Bean
        public SimpleController simpleController() {
            return new SimpleController();
        }
    }
    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    String home() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new SpringApplication(SimpleController.class).run(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is, with the auto-configuration, you get a lot of stuff for free, _including_ all of the Spring MVC setup. You have _zero_ MVC configuration. What is the purpose of using Spring boot if you want to configure everything manually. Spring boot configuration is opinionated, but any of those configurations can easily be overridden.

Comment: Was there a exact reason, you didn't want the auto-configuration. Maybe if it's just one single thing, someone can help you in figuring it out _with_ the auto-configuration, and just overriding/configuring some stuff

Comment: I want just an embedded  servlet container from spring boot. I want to avoid class path scan.

Comment: `@SpringBootApplication` is an alias for a combination of three annotations, `@Configuration`, `@ComponentScan`, and `@EnableAutoConfiguration`. The latter is required for the auto-configuration. So if you don't want the `@ComponentScan`, just use the other two. And you don't need the Jetty bean. The auto-configuration will set it up for you. You may need to configure the port though if you don't want the default 8080. You can just add `server.port=8888` in your `application.properties` file

Comment: Just @ EnableAutoConfiguration and @ Configuration doesn't work because @ Import is ignored and a controller class is created some else.

Comment: What happens if you put `@Configuration` on your `Ctx` class

Comment: There is no difference if Ctx has the annotation.